# Handle scrollbar without data in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make work Highstock with heaps of data (~100.000, weeks) like this:
when the user navigates to the page first, to save him or her from wasting time waiting for the database, s/he gets only the data related to the last 24 hours.
Meanwhile I want to let him to be able to navigate over the whole data set. As I have the *timestap* of the first and the last data (stored in 2 variables FIRST and LAST) I try to achieve this by setting the extremes of the navigator at chart initialization.
It seems like later when setting the data of the chart's series it also updates the navigator and the scrollbar, therefore they only show the given data period.

I made the following:

- chart initialization including:
  *navigator: { xAxis: { min: FIRST, max: LAST, } }*    // set first and last timestamps
- set last day data:
  *chart.series[0].setData(reply);*  //reply is from the DB

Here the navigator is set to last day.

- I even tried: *chart.xAxis[1].setExtremes(FIRST, LAST)* and *chart.series[1].xAxis.setExtremes(1000*first, 1000*last);*
  but these only affected the date of the navigator, the tracker and the scrollbar stayed still.

Could someone give me any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!
Bye,
klorti

Answer (score 0):

Only what comes to my mind is one of solutions below:

- get data for part which should be displayed (part points), and when chart will be generated, run ajax which will get full data (in the backround). After getting full data, you can use setData() function which replace "old" (part) data with full.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData()

- use loading module http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#loading
- catch setExtremes(http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes)  and then load data by ajax and setData()

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The goal is prevent the database system from executing queries unnecessarily as it serves other clients too and it really deals with myriad of data. I was looking for a solution that uses only the Highstock API. However it dosen't support this criteria, your solution is considerable. Anyway, finally I've chosen an alternative solution and cut off the navigator bar from the chart.